# Connect with a Database and store Post Data from a Form (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have made a Screenshot, so you have an overview about my situation.

https://gyazo.com/2845f91d2ff5acdfcea1d18d8f537607

So actually I want to code an CMS System in C# through the .NET Framework using the MVC.

I am trying to establish a successful connection from the MVC to the LocalDB.

I have 1 Project which is an ASP.net MVC Application and 1 Project which is an Sql Project. The Sql Project has a Main Db folder which is named dbo and in dbo there is a table folder, in this table are 2 entrys, username and password.

I have created a test-form in my asp.net mvc application.

My first question would be :

As you see on the picture, is the connection already established ? Is my connectionString right ?

My second question would be :

How can I store Data or check if Data from the User.sql table is correct ?

I am completely new to asp.net mvc, in PHP i do everything with PDO.

Comment: What technology are you using for data access? Entity Framework and ADO.NET are common choices.

Comment: I really dont know mate, i use the Sql Server Object Explorer

Comment: That is just to view and access the database independently. You will need to use a technology like EF or ADO.NET to work with the database in code.